# Getting data from listview and checking with if else

Tags: android, listview, if-statement

In my application I'm using a listview. I need to perform an if else check with selected data from listview. For that I created the following code. When I displayed the selected value, it displays correctly. But it isn't checked within the loop.

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
        String level = (String) (mainListView.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
        //  Toast.makeText(Listactivity.this, "" + level, 2000).show(); 

        if(level == "level-1")
        {
            Toast.makeText(Listactivity.this, "" + "selected levelel1", 2000).show();
        }
        else if(level == "level-2")
        {
         Toast.makeText(Listactivity.this, "" + "selected level 2", 2000).show();
        }
        else if(level == "level-3")
        {
         Toast.makeText(Listactivity.this, "" + "selected level3", 2000).show();
        }
        else
        {
         System.out.println("Level s not available");
        }

        }

     });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Use .equals()`.Because `==` compares `Strings Refrences not Characters of strings.`

Compares Strings using `.equals() when String is object`.When you declare string as String literal then you can compare strings using `==`

```
 if(level.equals("level-1"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(Listactivity.this, "" + "selected levelel1", 2000).show();
        }
        else if(level.equals("level-2"))
        {
         Toast.makeText(Listactivity.this, "" + "selected level 2", 2000).show();
        }
```

Comment: now it is working i did a mistake i put 'level-1' instead of 'Level-1'.Thank you so much ..

Comment: @PriyaRaj Use `level.equalsIgnoreCase("level-1")`

Answer (score 2):

Please try compare String do like this

```
if(level.equalsIgnoreCase("level-1")){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare String do like this

```
if(level.equals("level-1")){
}
```

Comment: Check your level values.is it equal to "level-1" or "level-2" and so on